# Какой, по вашему мнению, вариант заголовка предпочтительнее? Аргументируйте

Tags: стилистика

1. Чреззаборный тур на Боробудур
2. Череззаборный тур на Боробудур

Comment: Контекст мог бы помочь. Если не чреззаборный секрет.

Comment: В статье было описано проникновение на территорию храма в обход билетеров. Один из вариантов - мой, под другим она была опубликована в газете.

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант предпочтителен, проще в произношении и думаю, что на слух тоже. Общая беда — постановка этого «не слабого» слова в начале, неудобного вообще и не рассчитанного на прочтение без разгона. И ещё. «Туры в» бывают всё-таки, а «туры на» скорее островные, не территориальные. «В Боробудур» — явный перебор, поэтому убрал бы предлог и поделил бы фразу надвое, как с недавних пор водится: «Боробудур: Череззаборный тур».

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Пусть будет третий вариант. А после двоеточия, нужно с большой буквы...?

Comment: Это новое слово не в качестве названия не употреблял бы.